# Abort grunt-scaffold task conditionally using before() method

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I've got a grunt task that is using [grunt-scaffold](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scaffold) to copy files from my /dist/ folder to a stable release like /1.0.0/. I am having the scaffolding ask a few questions, mostly just asking for the 3 version numbers as seen on http://semver.org/. Below is the initConfig for the scaffold task. I'm going to run this as 'sudo grunt scaffold:publish'.

```
publish: {
    options: {
        questions: [{
                name: 'warn_confirm',
                type: 'input',
                message: 'WARNING This can overwrite files. Do you accept this risk?'
            },
            {
                name: 'major_vesion',
                type: 'input',
                message: 'What MAJOR version is this ? i.e. \'X.0.0\''
            },
            {
                name: 'minor_version',
                type: 'input',
                message: 'What MINOR version is this ? i.e. \'0.X.0\''
            },
            {
                name: 'patch_vesion',
                type: 'input',
                message: 'What PATCH version is this ? i.e. \'0.0.X\''
            }],
            template: {
                "dist/": "/{{major_vesion}}{{minor_version}}{{patch_vesion}}/"
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see the first question is asking if the person is willing to accept the risks (and confirming they are aware of the warning).

I see in the documentation (linked above) that there is a before method which is run before the files are copied over. I'd like to be able abort the scaffold if the use doesn't respond 'yes' or 'y' to the initial prompt. Can I simply return false to abort the rest of the scaffold process? Something similar to this psuedo-code:

```
if(warn_confirm !== 'y' || warn_confirm !== 'yes'){
    return false; // theoretically, cancel scaffold
}
```